# Больше одного параметра в action

Tags: php, yii

Всем привет! Как в Yii фреймворке сделать так, чтобы работала такая ссылка так, как я хочу:
`module_name/controller_name/action_name/$type/$id`
Ну я сделал экшен такой:

```
public function actionShow($type, $id)
{
   var_dump($id, $type);
}
```

Но, во-первых, Yii видит параметры только числа, поэтому $type должна быть числом, так ещё и при этом 2 числа тоже не видет. В итоге работает только так:

```
public function actionShow($type)
{
   var_dump($type);
}
```

При этом $type - обязательно число. Неужели мне для такого простого и логичного случая, нужно прописывать правило в urlManager ? Почему в документации они спокойно рассказывают о двух параметрах?
  Вырезка из документации:
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста :)
И ещё такой вопрос, тоже по ссылкам, вот в Phalcon автоматически название экшена в ссылке если (show_req), то название экшена ShowReq, в Yii этого нету ?

Comment: `module_name/controller_name/action_name/type/$type/id/$id`? "Неужели мне для такого простого и логичного случая, нужно прописывать правило в urlManager?" - неужели вы этого **не** делаете? И неужели до сих пор пишете на yii 1?

Comment: Да, ваш пример работает, но он не красивый, большая ссылка(( Подскажите тогда, что мне в urlManager написать пожалуйста? А то я попытался так: 'module_name/controller_name/action_name/<type:\w+>/<id:\w+>' =>'module_name/controller_name/action_name' - не работает(( да вроде вторая версия, я дорабатываю уже существующий проект. Мне не выбирать фреймворк

Comment: на глаз с синтаксисом правила все в порядке

Comment: Правило я может не в том месте пишу? В modules/module_name/config/main.php, в массиве: 'components'=>'urlManager'=>'rules'

Comment: ааа, всё, опять дело в этом runtime/cache - почистил - всё норм, спасибо! Скажите ещё про замену знака подчёркивания на заглавную букву? Почему это не продумали? Или может где настройку можно такую включить?

Comment: Я не очень понимаю, про что вы.

Comment: Ну вот ссылка чтобы была такая: module/controller/any_action, чтобы названия экшена было: actionAnyAction, без земли (подчёркивания "_"). В Phalcon это автоматически делается, в Yii такого нету?

Comment: Вы же сами задаете правило, какое вам хочется